# Shake Gesture Library for XNA?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna, shake

I am trying to use the Shake Gesture Library on a XNA project:
[Shake Gesture Library](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/article/Recipe_Shake_Gesture_Library), 
even though it's a four-step process, but I can't get it to work. I tried this on both HD7 and Omnia7.

However, when I run the sample it works perfectly. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You'll need to show some code. As a shot in the dark, you haven't got `<Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS"/>` as one of your capabilities in the `WMAppManifest` file.

Comment: i thin k keyboardP's psychic debugging powers will win this one.  the first sentence should be the comment, the second an answer :P

Comment: @John Gardner - Good idea. If the code is the same as the working sample, it's a pretty safe bet the capability is missing. Not sure why my psychic debugging power often works better than my normal one... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably missing a capability in your `WMAppManifestFile`. You can find this file in the `Properties` folder, from within the `Solution Explorer`. Add:

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS"/>
```

in the `Capabilities` section.